# How do I fit distributions to data sets in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to find a fit to my data using matlab but I'm having a lot of trouble, here's what ive done so far:

```
A = load('homicide_crime.txt')  % A is a two column array the first column is the year and the second column is crime in that year
norm_crime = (A(:,2)-mean(A(:,2)))/std(A(:,2)); 
[f,x]=hist(norm_crime,20);
plot(x,f/trapz(x,f))
y=normpdf(x,0,1);
hold on
plot(x,y)
```

This is the resulting plot

[image].

So i tried afterwards using the distribution fitter which gave me this.
 [image]
Neither of these things look right since the peak aren't aligned and the fit is too small.

Here is the data set for anyone intrested
https://pastebin.com/CyddrN1R.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Wthout the dataset, I honestly don't know what's going on so I cannot say if there is a problem or not.

Comment: You are trying to fit a normal distribution onto a dataset that is obviously not normally distributed (e.g. its distribution is skewed). Therefore there will never be a nice fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I think you are confusing data transformation with distribution fitting.

**DATA TRANSFORMATION**

In this approach, data is manipulated through a non-linear transformation in order to achieve a perfect fit. This means that it forces your data to follow the chosen distribution rule. To accomplish this with a normal distribution, all you have to do is applying the following code:

```
A = load('homicide_crime.txt');
years = A(:,1);
crimes = A(:,2);
figure(),histfit(crimes);

rank = tiedrank(crimes);
p = rank ./ (numel(rank) + 1);
crimes_normal = norminv(p,0,1);
figure(),histfit(crimes_normal);
```

Using the following manipulation:

```
crimes_normal = (crimes - mean(crimes)) ./ std(crimes);
```

that can also be written as:

```
crimes_normal = zscore(crimes);
```

you modify your observations so that they have `mu=0` and `sigma=1`, but this is far from making them perfectly fit a normal distribution.

**DISTRIBUTION FITTING**

In this approach, the parameters of the chosen distribution are calculated over the given dataset, and then random observations are drawn. On one side you have your empirical observations, and on the other side you have your fitted data. A goodness-of-fit test can finally tell you how well empirical observations fit the given distribution comparing them to theoretical observations.

Since your are working with a normal distribution, you know that it is fully described by two parameters: `mu` and `sigma`. Hence:

```
A = load('homicide_crime.txt');
years = A(:,1);
crimes_emp = A(:,2);

[mu,sigma] = normfit(crimes_emp);

% you can also use
% mu = mean(crimes);
% sigma = std(crimes);
% to achieve the same result

[f,x] = hist(crimes_emp);
crimes_the = normpdf(x,mu,sigma) .* max(f);

figure();
bar(x, (f ./ sum(f)));
hold on;
plot(x,crimes_the,'-r','LineWidth',2);
hold off;
```

And this returns something very close to the problem you originally noticed. As you can clearly see, without even running a Kolmogorov-Smirnov or an Anderson-Darling... your data doesn't fit a normal distribution well.

Comment: Thanks a bunch,this is my first time analysing data in this way so appreciate you clearing that up :). Also what would you suggest should i just analyse the data using the fit in your answer and state that the data doesn't fit the normal distribution very well so any observations will be unreliable?
Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You can try a non-parametric density estimation method. I used kernel density estimation (KDE) with the default normal distribution as the kernel, to obtain the result as shown below. The Matlab command for the same is `ksdensity()` and documentation can be found [here](https://in.mathworks.com/help/stats/ksdensity.html).

```
A = load('homicide_crime.txt')                     % load data
years = A(:,1);
values = A(:,2);
[f0,x0] = hist(values,100);                        % plot the actual histogram
[f1,x1,b1] = ksdensity(values);                    % KDE with automatically assigned bandwidth
[f2,x2,b2] = ksdensity(values,'Bandwidth',b1*0.6); % 60% of initial bandwidth (b1)
[f3,x3,b3] = ksdensity(values,'Bandwidth',b2*0.6); % 60% of previous bandwidth (b2) = 36% of initial bandwidth (b1)
[f4,x4,b4] = ksdensity(values,'Bandwidth',b3*0.6); % 60% of previous bandwidth (b3) = 21.6% of initial bandwidth (b1)

figure; hold on;
bar(years, f0/(sum(f0)*10) );                      % scaled for visualization 
plot(years, f1, 'y')
plot(years, f2, 'c')
plot(years, f3, 'g')
plot(years, f4, 'r','linewidth',3)                 % Final fit
```

[image]

In the code above, I first plot the histogram and then calculate the kde without any user specified bandwidth. This leads to an oversmooth fitting (yellow curve). With a few trials by reducing the bandwidth as only 60% of the previous iteration, I finally was able to get the closest fit (red curve). You can play around the bandwidth to get a still better desirable fit.